# How to keep yeoman angular app alive using grunt-forever?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, forever

I have a yeoman angular based app that I run with `grunt serve`.

It is critical that I keep this application running all the time. I've used forever before and it's worked fine but it normally works on a particular js file. Whereas I want to use it with the `grunt serve` task.

I found a plugin called grunt-forever - https://github.com/bustardcelly/grunt-forever - but I don't know how to set up my gruntfile.js to use it to call the `grunt serve` command.

The server section of my grunt file is the standard one that gets generated by yeoman for an angular application. It is as follows  -

```
  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'express:prod', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'bower-install',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'express:dev',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });
```

Anyone know how to use grunt-forever to call that command?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure this out myself today, and came across this post on my way to finding out.

I'm still a bit new to all this, but came to the conclusion that grunt is more use for dev tasks, and not recommended for production. (I may be wrong on this).

The main pitfalls I had were trying to use grunt (and not being able to work out the magical incantation), and then once I figured out I should be using node directly, getting the paths working.

This is what I did in the end, for my app generated with DaftMonk's generator-angular-fullstack :

```
sudo npm install forever forever-service -g
cd ~/<project directory>/server

sudo forever-service install <service name> -s /<full path to project directory>/server/app.js -e "PATH=/usr/local/bin:\$PATH" --start
```

The to verify what's happening:

```
tail -f /var/logs/<service name>.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration which is working as far as I have checked. It is  able to recover from simple errors and restart the server.

```
//load the forever task
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-forever');
// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    ....
    forever: {
      server1:{
        options: {
          index: 'server/app.js'
        }
      }
    },
  });

...

grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
  if (target === 'dist') {
    return grunt.task.run(['build', 'env:all', 'forever:server1:start', 'express:prod', 'wait', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
  }
});
```

*PS:* I read your other yeoman question and thought you must have asked this question as well.